# ES6 - Failed to load module in localhost and python server

Tags: python, mime-types, es6-modules, httpserver

I try to learn and make practice ES6 Modules. I created simple project.

**main.html**

```
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="ie=edge">
    <title>Document</title>
     <script type="module" src="main.js"></script>
</head>
<body></body>
</html>
```

**main.js**

```
import {PI, Sum} from './js/bk_math'
console.log("hello");
```

It gives me an error

> Failed to load module script: The server responded with a
>   non-JavaScript MIME type of "text/plain". Strict MIME type checking is
>   enforced for module scripts per HTML spec.

I use VS Code IDE and I start server with

> python -m http.server 9200

Chrome version: 78.0.3904.97
Python version: Python 3.7.0

Should I change server or browser? How can I run it in my local?

Comment: You should change (or reconfigure) your server, so that it serves the script with the appropriate mime type.

Comment: Shouldn't it be ```import {PI, Sum} from './js/bk_math.js'``` with the .js?